# Cannot create AmazonS3Client object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

In a Java project I have used `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.6.12` aws dependency in the gradle. And I upgraded the aws dependency to `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.660`. And I used the following way to create `s3client` object.

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials,clientConfiguration);
```

And this way is not working when I upgraded the dependency. So, I have tried in the following way also,

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key"); 
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
```

This also didn't work for me. I am getting a null reference. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: have u set your credentials using environment variables?

Comment: No I am passing them from a configuration file.

Comment: You need to replace the `"access_key"` and `"secret_key"` strings with the actual values here: `new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key");`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the credentials for your Java program to build the Amazon service client. Here are the details of different ways to set them

> When you initialize a new service client without supplying any
>   arguments, the AWS SDK for Java attempts to find AWS credentials by
>   using the default credential provider chain implemented by the
>   DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain class. The default credential
>   provider chain looks for credentials in this order:
>
> 1. Environment variables–AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. The
>      AWS SDK for Java uses the EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider class
>      to load these credentials.
> 2. Java system properties–aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey. The AWS SDK
>      for Java uses the SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider to load these
>      credentials.
> 3. The default credential profiles file– typically located at
>      ~/.aws/credentials (location can vary per platform), and shared by
>      many of the AWS SDKs and by the AWS CLI. The AWS SDK for Java uses the
>      ProfileCredentialsProvider to load these credentials.
> 4. You can create a credentials file by using the aws configure command
>      provided by the AWS CLI, or you can create it by editing the file with
>      a text editor. For information about the credentials file format, see
>      AWS Credentials File Format.
> 5. Amazon ECS container credentials– loaded from the Amazon ECS if the
>      environment variable AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI is set.
>      The AWS SDK for Java uses the ContainerCredentialsProvider to load
>      these credentials.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html